# Additional horizontal X-Axis in Google Charts (Column Chart) based on data fetched from server

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, charts, google-visualization

I'm retrieving various type of data (datetime, string, int) in my aspx code for populating Google Charts using this code from server side

```
var chartData;
$.ajax({
        url: "Default2.aspx/GetChartData",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            chartData = data.d;
        },
        error: function () {
        alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
        }
        }).done(function () {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        });
    });

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data);
}
```

Now I want to show datetime and string values on X-Axis and int (multiple) values in Column Chart, also I have to filter chart values based on datetime and string values. Is there any method using which we can achieve it?

Comment: @WhiteHat you have any idea about it?

Comment: google offers 5 different controls for filtering data, including `DateRangeFilter` and `StringFilter`, all of which you can bind to a single / multiple charts, see --> [Controls and Dashboards](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) -- as for getting _datetime and string values on X-Axis_, need a little more info, the first column of the data table drives the x-axis -- please share a sample of `data.d` and an example of how you want the x-axis labels to appear, something like this? --> `2017-04-13 07:24 am`

Comment: @WhiteHat Actually table which I'm using has 30+ columns out of which I'm using 5 (String, datetime, datetime, int, int, int) for populating the chart. I want the first and second column on X-Axis and last three to draw the column chart. So I want my X-Axis label to appear like --> " John 13 April 2017  " (UserName & Date). There are multiple users and after drawing the chart  I need to select Users and Date using dropdowns which will dynamically filter the data. Hope you're able to understand, if not I can explain again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the chart expects the x-axis to be in the first column only

we can use a DataView to combine the first two columns into one

then use the DataView to draw the chart, see following snippet...

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

  // use view to combine first two columns
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  var viewColumns = [{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 0) + ' ' + dt.getValue(row, 1);
    },
    label: 'x-axis',
    type: 'string'
  }];

  // add remaining columns to view
  $.each(new Array(data.getNumberOfColumns()), function (colIndex) {
    // skip first two columns
    if (colIndex < 2) {
      return;
    }
    viewColumns.push(colIndex);
  });

  // set view columns
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  // use view to draw chart
  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view);
}
```

Comment: So now I'll first filter the data using first two columns then I'll combine them both and show the data. Eureka. I'll tag you when I'll implement the code. Thanks @WhiteHat